# issue in reading gzip file directly in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

No problem in reading the tar.gz but I see lot of gibberish in the final o/p Used:(on pyspark)

```
lines=sc.textFile("abc.tar.gz")
count = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(add)
print count.collect()
```

My o/p has lot of x00\x00\ Any one ?